# Matching sets in SQL when cross-referencing

Tags: sql, select, count, relational-division, cross-reference

I have the following tables :

- books : a list of books
- tags : a list of tags (novel, biography, etc.)
- xrefbookstags : cross-referencing table (a book has multiple tags)

What I would like to do is given a set of tags find the books whose tags match **exactly** with the set. Here is what I have tried :

```sql
SELECT B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual
    FROM books B INNER JOIN xrefbookstags XRBT 
        ON XRBT.idBooks=B.id JOIN tags T
        ON XRBT.idTags=T.id
    WHERE T.name IN ('novel','biography')
```

This gives me an inclusion not an equality of sets. So I figured I should count the number of tags within the set and match the size of the set.

```sql
SELECT B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual
    FROM books B INNER JOIN xrefbookstags XRBT 
        ON XRBT.idBooks=B.id JOIN tags T
        ON XRBT.idTags=T.id
    WHERE T.name IN ('novel','biography') AND count(T.id)=2
```

but this fails. So here comes my question : I could I match sets in this cross-referencing context ?

Answer (score 2):

You want those books for which

a) there is no required tag that's missing for that book, **AND**
b) there is no tag for that book that's not in the required tags list.

Put the id's of those tag names into a table (here done on the fly) and do this. (no SQL Fiddle or CREATE TABLE/INSERT sample data, so I didn't run this to check every detail)

```
WITH TagIDs(id) AS ( --required tag ids
  SELECT id
  FROM tags
  WHERE name in ('novel', 'biography')
)

  SELECT B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual --select those books
  FROM books B

  WHERE --a)
  NOT EXISTS (  -- there is no
    SELECT * FROM TagIDs --  required tag
    WHERE TagIDs.id NOT IN ( -- that's missing
      SELECT XRBT.idTags FROM xrefbookstags XRBT -- from the list of tags
      WHERE XRBT.idBooks=B.id -- for this particular book
    )
  )
  AND --b)
  NOT EXISTS ( -- there is no
    SELECT * FROM xrefbookstags XRBT --tag
    WHERE XRBT.idBooks=B.id --for this particular book
    AND XRBT.idTags NOT IN ( --that's missing
      SELECT id FROM TagIDs --from the list of required tags
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual
FROM books B
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM xrefbookstags XRBT 
    INNER JOIN Tags T ON XRBT.idTags=T.id
    WHERE XRBT.idBooks=B.id
    AND T.name = 'novel'
)
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM xrefbookstags XRBT 
    INNER JOIN Tags T ON XRBT.idTags=T.id
    WHERE XRBT.idBooks=B.id
    AND T.name = 'biography'
) 
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM xrefbookstags XRBT 
    INNER JOIN Tags T ON XRBT.idTags=T.id
    WHERE XRBT.idBooks=B.id
    AND T.name NOT IN ('novel','biography')
)
```

Comment: Actually I do not have control over the input tags, it comes in a variable. Here `('novel','biography')` is just an example. I could output COUNT(T.id) and add GROUP BY T.id at the end. But this way I post-process the SQL output. I would like to get all the result using only SQL and possibly as a compact request :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  The most general approach is to use `group by` and put the logic in the `having` clause.  For your case:

```
SELECT B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual
FROM books B INNER JOIN
     xrefbookstags XRBT 
     ON XRBT.idBooks = B.id JOIN
     tags T
     ON XRBT.idTags = T.id
group by B.name, B.author, B.id, B.finished, B.manual
having sum(case when t.name = 'novel' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'biography' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name not in ('novel', 'biography') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The logic is as follows.  The first clause is true when at least one tag is `'novel'`.  The second clause is true when at least one clause is `'biography'` and the third is true when there are no other tags.

This is easily generalizable.  If you wanted books that had these two tags but could have others, just leave out the third clause:

```
having sum(case when t.name = 'novel' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'biography' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you wanted books that had one or the other:

```
having sum(case when t.name = 'novel' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when t.name = 'biography' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you wanted books that had these two plus 'historical', then you would just add it in:

```
having sum(case when t.name = 'novel' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'biography' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'historical' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

And, if you wanted that but not about cooking:

```
having sum(case when t.name = 'novel' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'biography' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'historical' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.name = 'cooking' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

EDIT:

If you have a comma delimited list of tags that you want to match, then you can do:

```
having sum(case when ','+@List+',' not like '%,'+t.name+',%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       count(distinct t.name) = 1 + len(@list) - len(replace(@list, ',', ''))
```

The first clause says that all tags are in the list.  The second says that the length of the tags are the length of the list.

This is essentially pseudo-code.  Different databases have different names for the `len()` function and different ways of concatenating strings together and different ways to express a variable value.  But the intention should be clear.

Comment: Same remark as @Tim Schmelter, I just have a variable containing tags so the size could be anything. I could generate the SQL but I would like to keep it light. Is there any built-in feature in SQL to achieve this ?